# Contour integral with branch cuts?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, parametrization, branch-cuts

Let $C$ be the positively oriented unit circle, and consider the function $z^{-3/4}$.

(a). Show that if $f(z)$ is the principal branch of $z^{-3/4}$, i.e., $$f(z)=exp[\frac{-3}{4}Logz],$$ where $|z|>0$, $-\pi<Argz<\pi$, then $$\int_{C}f(z)=4\sqrt{2}i$$

For this, I tried integrating $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (e^{i\theta})^{-3/4}(ie^{i\theta})d\theta$, which got me $4i\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$.  Then I tried to integrate the same thing between the bounds of $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$, and got another big mess, which didn't add up to what it was supposed to.

Further, for part (b), the instructions say to integrate the same function but $g(z)=exp[\frac{-3}{4}logz]$, and $0<argz<2\pi$.  Then the integral should equal $-4+4i$.

How will this one be different than the one before it?

Comment: Why are you integrating from $-\pi /2$ to $\pi/2$ rather than from $-\pi$ to $\pi$?

Comment: Because that's what my teacher told me to use when I tried asking her.

Comment: Hmm not sure what your teacher was going for there. There's subtlety with branch cuts so maybe she was making a more complicated point. Anyhow, the answers can be obtained by integrating $i e^{i\theta/4}$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and $0$ to $2\pi$ respectively. They can be different cause the two branches are different functions.

Comment: There is a potential issue about 'integrating over the unit circle' because the functions are both undefined at one point on the unit circle, but this is just a jump discontinuity that doesn't cause any difficulty with integrability. It is thus simplest to just start and end the contour on the branch cut rather than break the integral up piecewise when you cross it. (Maybe it was related to this point why your instructor was doing a piecewise integral of some sort.)